# UITableViewRowAction doesn't work after swipe the cell can't be swiped

Tags: ios, swift, uitableviewrowaction

Now I have an UITableview , and some CollectionviewCell in the same viewController, if user click the collectionviewCell, tableview will reload different datas, some have multiple sections, some not, and also some cells can be swipe , some may not.

Now my problem is if user swipe those cell can be swiped , it all works fine, but if swipe those can't be swiped cells, then those can be swiped cells doesn't work , until jump to other viewController , and back , again it all works fine. Don't know how to solve this bug. Need a hand!

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: did you try tableview.reloadData() ?